# Awk: Scripts on the path?

Tags: bash, awk, path

Is there a way to put little `awk` scriptoids on the path?

For example, I have this really useful collation operation:

```
// collate-csv.awk
FNR > 1 || NR == 1
```

And I can use it in all sorts of great ways:

```
xargs -a $(find * -name *.csv) awk -F',' -f collate-csv.awk | ...
```

The only problem is I don't have a way to call my awk tools from anywhere.  With an executable shell script, I can drop it into a bin folder on the path.  Is there a mechanism in linux where I can make these non-executable `awk` source files available from anywhere I go in the filesystem?

(with the qualification that the "mechanism" is not a "why don't you just hit it with a hammer"-style kludge)

Comment: That script can be reduced to just `FNR>1 || NR==1`, no need for the `next` and 2 `print`s. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Environment-Variables and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Include-Files for information relevant to your question.

Comment: @EdMorton edit made, that is a different level of brevity than I knew awk was capable of. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @Roamia's answer you can use `AWKPATH` variable for a list of directory where to look for `collate-csv.awk`

```
AWKPATH=${HOME}/include/awk:/some/other/path
export AWKPATH
xargs -a $(find * -name *.csv) awk -f collate-csv.awk -F',' | ...
```

please note

- `.awk` extension is not mandatory, just be consistent,
- shebang line e.g. `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` is mandatory when script is used standalone as a script (no `awk -f` call),
- you will have to use `awk -f` (and awk know how to use `AWKPATH`, bash don't)

Comment: You should mention that AWKPATH is an extension to POSIX that's supported by GNU awk, idk about any others. I don't see anything in your script that'd make a shebang mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Create an executable `awk` script and add it to your `$PATH`

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin"
cat >"$HOME/bin/collate-csv <<'x'
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#
# collate-csv.awk
#
NR == 1 { print }
FNR == 1 { next }
{print}
x

chmod a+x "$HOME/bin/collate-csv"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Now you can use `collate-csv` just as you would any other command

```
xargs -a $(find * -name *.csv) collate-csv -F',' | ...
```

Comment: suppose i created a `${HOME}/include/awk` and dropped my awk source code in there for more advanced tools.  Does awk need any coercion to link the source code to the executables?

Comment: @Chris my proposal is that the `awk` scripts become executable. So you can put them in any directory you like, add that directory to your `$PATH`, and they'll be available exactly as any other command. I've chosen `"$HOME/bin"` because that's what I use everywhere for all my personal scripts and programs. You could just as easily use `"$HOME/include/awk"`